# Cannot seem to copy a rectangle more than +0 in y using Camera.copyToByteArray()

Tags: actionscript-3, camera

I'm using the FlashyWrappers video encoder to record a webcam session, and I want to use the Camera's [copyToByteArray()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#copyToByteArray()) method to grab only a section from the center of the image.

The code (in an event handler) looks something like this:

```
// variables
var frame :ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var rect  :Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);

// grab frame
camera.copyToByteArray(rect, frame);

// encode frame
encoder.addVideoFrame(frame);
```

The overall process is sound, and I get video output, but the problem is that the captured region is locked in y at 0, so is as if I passed in:

```
new Rectangle(100, 0, 200, 200);
```

This makes the method useless for anything other than full frame captures (which is not what I want as we're doing facial capture).

EDIT: I've added a Gist here, with demo code where you can drag a rectangle to capture the region. It still won't work, where bitmapData.draw() does:

https://gist.github.com/davestewart/80d55538a615aa2eacaa

Any ideas?

Comment: it's likely a bug in the framework, contact the author.

Comment: I think it's a bug with AS3... the framework just spits out what it is given. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I'm siding with @BotMaster's comment on this one... Never had such a problem with `rectangle` before.

Since `frame` holds a byte array of pixel values why not check what you have by using `Loader` before using `encoder.addVideoFrame(frame);`? If your snapshot image (from bytes) looks okay but the encoded version looks wrong then you know where the problem is...

**Try something like this:**

```
//# variables
var frame       : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var rect        : Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
var img_loader  : Loader = new Loader();

//# grab frame
camera.copyToByteArray(rect, frame);

//# check image before encode
img_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgBytes_complete );
img_loader.loadBytes( frame );

function onImgBytes_complete (e:Event)
{
    var test_BMP : Bitmap = new Bitmap(); 
    test_BMP = img_loader.content as Bitmap;
    addChild(test_BMP); //or add to specific test container
}

//# encode frame
//encoder.addVideoFrame(frame);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @VC-One, unfortunately I couldn't get your example to work (it failed on loadBytes) but I've added an interactive example as a Gist, comparing the result you get compared with bitmapData.draw() (which is the result I expected): https://gist.github.com/davestewart/80d55538a615aa2eacaa

Try it out and get back to me!

Thanks.